# Photoshop: How do you use the path selection tool to make the edges of a rounded rectangle straight?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

## Photoshop: How do you use the path selection tool to make the edges of a rounded rectangle straight???

How would you change the edges of a rounded rectangle to be straight, I'm sorry if the title is confusing what I'm trying to do is make a rounded rectangle look like this but no matter how hard I try it always curves and if you show me how to do that it would be very helpful. An example of what I am trying to do is below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw a new rectangle with the Shape tool -- that'll take 3 seconds... as opposed to 20 minutes trying to "unround" corners.